# VC dimension of sine family is infinite?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, mathematical-statistics, definition, vc-dimension

From what I understand, the VC dimension of an hypothesis class is given by the maximum number of points in general position (or random) on the domain space that can be arbitrarily labeled by the hypothesis class.

From [lecture notes](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/fa12/cse291-b/vcnotes.pdf) and videos I learned that the hypothesis class of sine functions on the real line has infinite VC dimension. However, the proofs that I see so far always seem to use one example of points to show that the sine can arbitrarily label them, namely the set of points given by {$2^{-m} | m \in \mathbb{N}$}. However, an example does not prove that any set of points in general position on the line can be labeled arbitrarily. So I am confused about the actual definition and the proof. From the regularity of the sine, I would expect that there are set of points that cannot be labeled arbitrarily using the sine function.

Questions:

1) Does anyone have a proof for more general set of points?
2) Where is my misunderstanding of the definition of the VC dimension or of the proof (see Example 3 on p.4 in the link)?

Any comments that point me to the right direction of correct my train of thought are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

<sub>Incidentally, I think the proof in the linked notes is slightly wrong; if $y_i = 1$ but all the trailing $y_i$ are zero, you'd get a sine of zero. This can be fixed by adding a tiny amount to $w$; [page 5 here](https://cs.nyu.edu/%7Emohri/ml16/sol2.pdf) also gives a correct construction.</sub>

From your [linked notes](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/fa12/cse291-b/vcnotes.pdf):

> The VC dimension of $\mathcal H$ is the size of the largest set of examples that can be shattered by $\mathcal H$. The VC dimension is infinite if for all $m$, there is a set of $m$ examples shattered by $\mathcal H$.

*Usually*, one considers a set of points in "general position" and shows that they can be shattered. This avoids issues like collinear points for a linear classifier.

But it could be the case that the points need to be arranged in some special way, e.g. $\{ 2^{-m} \mid m \in \mathbb N\}$, for the classifier family to shatter them; that's still okay for the VC dimension, which says "there is a set of size $m$ which can be shattered," not "most sets of size $m$ can be shattered" or "this particular set of size $m$ can be shattered."

I don't know for sure that sine functions shatter points in "general position," where here "general position" should mean something like "add infinitesimal noise to each point," though I'd expect they do. (They actually can't shatter the set $\{x, 2x, 3x, 4x\}$ for any $x$ – see [page 4 here](https://cs.nyu.edu/%7Emohri/ml16/sol2.pdf) – but that's not general position.)

An example $\mathcal H$ with infinite VC dimension that cannot shatter "most" sets would be the set of hypotheses on $\mathbb R^d$ defined as, for $w \in \mathbb R$,
$$
h_w(\vec x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } x_j \ne 0 \text{ for any j > 1} \\ \operatorname{sign}(\sin(w x_1)) &\text{otherwise} .\end{cases}
$$
Clearly this does not shatter all, or "most", sets on $\mathbb R^n$: if *any* points don't lie exactly on the $x_1$ axis, it can't shatter that set. So it can't shatter anything in "general position" (since it can *only* assign zero to general-position points).

Still, its VC dimension is infinite, because it can shatter any set of the form $\{ (2^{-m}, 0, \dots, 0) \mid m \in \mathbb N \}$.

The reason for this definition is exactly that it allows you to give worst-case, distribution-independent bounds on learning rates. If we defined a VC-like "dimension" for "most" sets of points, then e.g. the one-dimensional sine family above might have low "dimension," but bounds based on that "dimension" learning bounds couldn't possibly apply for distributions giving points only on the $x_1$ axis.

The [Rademacher complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher_complexity) is one example of a finer-grained notion of complexity that can account for a function class's complexity on a *particular* set or distribution. In this (extreme) case, you could easily show that the Rademacher complexity would be zero for sets in general position, and hence for distributions which almost surely give general-position sample sets, there is no generalization error. But VC analyses are worst case over all possible distributions.

Comment: Thanks! Also for the reference to the Rademacher complexity. That was the confusion, I thought that the definition requires that all sets are shattered. Do you know if there is any reason for the milder condition? A single set that can be classified is easier to satisfy than the requirement than any random sets have to be shattered. Just wondering...

Comment: If you only say something about the algorithm's complexity on "random sets," then your learning theory bounds will only apply for distributions sufficiently similar to what you meant by "random" in the first place. If it holds for all sets, then results like Sauer's Lemma can hold uniformly. You can do the analysis for certain kinds of input distributions, but it's more complicated to state what you mean and there are more fiddly bits.

Comment: This is very interesting, thank you. This has been very helpful. However, I still find it strange that the definition of the VC dimension depends on actually finding a set that can be shattered, as opposed to showing that all sets of a given cardinality and with linearly independent elements can be shattered.

Answer (score 3):

Great answer by @djs. I want to add an answer to the following comment by @HCRuiz:
*"I still find it strange that the definition of the VC dimension depends on actually finding a set that can be shattered, as opposed to showing that all sets of a given cardinality and with linearly independent elements can be shattered."*

I see your point and I believe the confusions stems from the interpretation that you're giving to the VC dimension. In fact, it is not a measure of the general classification power of your function class, and it is more a statistical learning theory tool. For how counterintuitive it may seem, it should be used to lower bound the size of your dataset. You don't want to use a too powerful function class for the data you're given, because that one will not be generalizing well, as it is able to simply memorize any mapping from your points to your labels. From this perspective, it now shouldn't seem strange anymore that we take into consideration arbitrarily well-positioned points, as it represents a worst-case scenario in our classification task.

Hope this clears your doubts!

Comment: Yes, this is a nice intuitive explanation. For the worst case scenario it is indeed a single example needed, I didn't see it like it. It's like finding a counter example in a proof.